# How can I disable DNS caching in Safari?

Tags: macos, caching, dns, safari

I'd like to disable Safari on Mac OS X from performing DNS caching.
Is there a way to do that through configuration or any other setting ?

Comment: DNS caching is handled bu the OS, not Safari. See `man dscacheutil`.

Comment: @PaulR: In Windows each browser has its own DNS caching settings. Are you sure Firefox and Chrome adhere to Mac OS X tools ?

Comment: Well even if they don't there will still be DNS caching at the OS level.

Comment: Not sure about Firefox, but at least Chrome for Mac OS X have his own DNS cache. You can manage it typing "chrome://net-internals/#dns" in address bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clear the OS cache:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Disable Safari DNS prefetching:

```
defaults write com.apple.safari WebKitDNSPrefetchingEnabled -boolean false
```

Comment: This defaults write doesn't work on El Capitan, even tried restarting Safari. To test I added a loopback entry for Google to my hosts file and reload in Safari still worked.

Answer (score 2):

Update: for Yosemite to clear the cache you want:

```
sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches
```

Answer (score 1):

In Safari 12.1 this should have been moved to:

```
defaults read com.apple.Safari WebKitPreferences.dnsPrefetchingEnabled
```

With:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitPreferences.dnsPrefetchingEnabled -boolean false
```

you should be able to disable it.